# Pandas join on columns with different names

Tags: python, sql, pandas, merge

I have two different data frames that I want to perform some sql operations on. Unfortunately, as is the case with the data I'm working with, the spelling is often different.

See the below as an example with what I thought the syntax would look like where userid belongs to df1 and username belongs to df2.  Anyone help me out?

```
 # not working - I assume some syntax issue?
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = [['userid'=='username', 'column1']], how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

When the names are different, use the `xxx_on` parameters instead of `on=`:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=  ['userid', 'column1'],
                   right_on= ['username', 'column1'], 
                   how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach is to use `join` setting the index of the right hand side `DataFrame` to the columns `['username', 'column1']`:

```
df1.join(df2.set_index(['username', 'column1']), on=['userid', 'column1'], how='left')
```

The output of this `join` *merges* the matched keys from the two differently named key columns, `userid` and `username`, into a single column named after the key column of `df1`, `userid`; whereas the output of the `merge` maintains the two as separate columns. To illustrate, consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'pID' : [21,22,23,24,25,26], 'Values' : [435,33,45,np.nan,np.nan,12]})
##    ID  Values  pID
## 0   1   435.0   21
## 1   2    33.0   22
## 2   3    45.0   23
## 3   4     NaN   24
## 4   5     NaN   25
## 5   6    12.0   26

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [4,4,5], 'pid' : [24,25,25], 'Values' : [544, 545, 676]})
##    ID  Values  pid
## 0   4     544   24
## 1   4     545   25
## 2   5     676   25

pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['ID', 'pID'], right_on=['ID', 'pid']))
##    ID  Values_x  pID  Values_y   pid
## 0   1     435.0   21       NaN   NaN
## 1   2      33.0   22       NaN   NaN
## 2   3      45.0   23       NaN   NaN
## 3   4       NaN   24     544.0  24.0
## 4   5       NaN   25     676.0  25.0
## 5   6      12.0   26       NaN   NaN

df1.join(df2.set_index(['ID','pid']), how='left', on=['ID','pID'], lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y'))
##    ID  Values_x  pID  Values_y
## 0   1     435.0   21       NaN
## 1   2      33.0   22       NaN
## 2   3      45.0   23       NaN
## 3   4       NaN   24     544.0
## 4   5       NaN   25     676.0
## 5   6      12.0   26       NaN
```

Here, we also need to specify `lsuffix` and `rsuffix` in `join` to distinguish the overlapping column `Value` in the output. As one can see, the output of `merge` contains the extra `pid` column from the right hand side `DataFrame`, which IMHO is unnecessary given the context of the merge. Note also that the `dtype` for the `pid` column has changed to `float64`, which results from upcasting due to the `NaN`s introduced from the unmatched rows.

This aesthetic output is gained at a cost in performance as the call to `set_index` on the right hand side `DataFrame` incurs some overhead. However, a quick and dirty profile shows that this is not too horrible, roughly `30%`, which may be worth it:

```
sz = 1000000 # one million rows
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.arange(sz), 'pID' : np.arange(0,2*sz,2), 'Values' : np.random.random(sz)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.concatenate([np.arange(sz/2),np.arange(sz/2)]), 'pid' : np.arange(0,2*sz,2), 'Values' : np.random.random(sz)})

%timeit pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', left_on=['ID', 'pID'], right_on=['ID', 'pid'])
## 818 ms ± 33.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df1.join(df2.set_index(['ID','pid']), how='left', on=['ID','pID'], lsuffix='_x', rsuffix='_y')
## 1.04 s ± 18.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```